# React Navigation: How to update navigation title for parent, when value comes from redux and gets updated in child?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) and have a StackNavigator with a  **ParentScreen** and a **ChildScreen**.

Both screens have the same navigation bar with a dynamic value from redux. Implemented like described in [Issue #313](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/313)

This works as expected. When I'm in DetailScreen and I update the value for the count variable, it also updates the value in the navigation bar.

Problem is, if I go back to the parent scene, there is still the old value in the navigation bar. It doesn't update to the current value in redux store.

**Child**

[image: screen shot 2017-04-11 at 15 20 28]

**Parent** (when I go back)

[image: screen shot 2017-04-11 at 15 21 31]

**ChildScreen**

```
class ChildScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: ({ state }) => `Total: ${state.params && state.params.count ?  state.params.count : ''}`
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.count != this.props.count) {
      this.props.navigation.setParams({ count: nextProps.count });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button onPress={() => this.props.increment()} title="Increment" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**ParentScreen**

```
class ParentScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
  title: ({ state }) => `Total: ${state.params && state.params.count ?    state.params.count : ''}`
  };
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: Is it the value that does not update, or is it the render method that is not called ?

Comment: More information is necessary to debug this: are your components `connect`ed? What is the implementation of `increment`? How have you integrated your app to Redux? Consider updating the question to include more information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My advice:

1. Make sure that `ParentScreen` is connected through react-redux `connect` function.
2. If you want the title of `ParentScreen` to get updated automatically when the state of the store changes, connecting it won't be enough. You will have to use the `componentWillReceiveProps` like you are doing in the `ChildScreen` Component.

**Bonus**: you could create a Higher Order Component for encapsulating that behaviour, like this:

```
const withTotalTitle = Component => props => {
  class TotalTitle extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
      title: ({ state }) => `Total: ${state.params && state.params.count ?  state.params.count : ''}`
    };

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      if (nextProps.count != this.props.count) {
        this.props.navigation.setParams({ count: nextProps.count });
      }
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <Component {...props}/>
      );
    }
  }

  return connect(state => { count: state.total })(TotalTitle); // update this (I have no idea what the structure your state looks like)
};
```

And then you could use it like this:

```
const ChildScreen = withTotalTitle(({ increment }) => (
  <View>
    <Button onPress={() => increment()} title="Increment" />
  </View>
));

const ParentScreen = withTotalTitle(() => (
  <View>
    <Text>Whatever ParentScreen is supposed to render.</Text>
  </View>
));
```

Comment: Note: `componentWillReceiveProps` has been deprecated since [this update on March 2018](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html). Instead, it is encouraged to use the static method `getDerivedStateFromProps`. As it is a static function, you won't have access to `this.props` to compare `nextProps` against anymore, so to get it to work, you'd now have to 'mirror' the `count` property (i.e. keep a copy of `count` in your component's state such that it is accessible via `state.count`).

Answer (score 2):

OP, this is likely to be a problem with your redux implementation. Are you familiar with how redux implements its store? I see no mention here which means it is likely that your increment function is merely updating the child component's state instead of dispatching actions and reducers. Please have a look at a proper redux implementation like this one: https://onsen.io/blog/react-state-management-redux-store/

Answer (score 2):

Have a common reducer for both parent and child. That way all the components(parent and child in your case) will get notified when the state changes.

Write a connect function for both parent and child. You'll receive the updated state in componentWillReceiveProps method. Use it as you please.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use props in order to pass the incremented value from child to parent component.

find the article below. It has a great example of communications between parent and child components.

http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/

Thanks