# React Native Navigation Updating Data

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist

I am building an app where I am using **Redux** and the **React-Navigation** library. I have a list of workouts in a FlatList:

```js
 <FlatList
        style={{ backgroundColor: colors.background }}
        data={this.props.workoutsList}
        renderItem={({ item }) =>
          <ListItem workout={item} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Workout', item)} />
        }
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
```

This shows my list properly, and I can navigate to the specific Workout page for each row I click on, and am provided the attached workout on each click. On this specific workout page, I have an Edit Workout form where users can, for example, update the name and time of the workout.

All of this is no problem...the issue I have comes when I press the back button on the menu that takes me back to the main list of all workouts. The FlatList is still showing the old data and is a source of my problem. It is caching this data so my new saves are not being shown, and as a consequence when I click on the list item again, it attaches the old workout information rather than the newest one I just saved. (hope that makes sense)

I have seen a somewhat similar question: [React Navigation: How to update navigation title for parent, when value comes from redux and gets updated in child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43347536/react-navigation-how-to-update-navigation-title-for-parent-when-value-comes-fr) but it does not quite encapsulate my main question:

**Is it possible where a FlatList can update a specific row from a redux setup, while also maintaining it's scroll position?**

I see this working extremely nicely on the Facebook app....as someone is scrolling down their Wall, let's say they click on the item saying "xx Comments". This will navigate the app to a page showing only this post. You can Like/Comment and when you press the back arrow, you are brought back exactly in the scroll position of the Wall you were before AND the number of likes/comments has been update to show your contribution. Is this possible in React Native?

If this is not possible...does anybody know how to at least refresh a page when navigating from a back button in React-Navigation?

**EDIT** I am open to using another navigation library if there is a better setup somewhere else!

**UPDATE**
I have attempted several ways to solve this problem, one way I tried was this:

When I made a successful save of the form, I dispatched an action of 'NEEDS_REFRESHING'. This set a redux prop that I picked up on the main FlatList page. In the render of that page, I had an:

```js
if (this.props.needsRefreshing) {
  console.log('Needs Refreshing');
  this.props.getWorkouts();
}
```

I was seeing the console, and my FlatList page was properly refreshing (it wasn't bringing me back to the correct scroll position as it just refreshed the main list). but I always got a warning from React Native saying:

```js
Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within
`render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be
a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an
anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
```

When I moved this to componentWillMount, the proper refreshing changes were then never getting called and even a console.log in componentWillMount would not show up.

Comment: What debugging have you done? Is `render` being called at all when you update the redux store? Could you provide the code for your action/reducer

Comment: Hi @sooper...thanks for interest. I have updated my question with some more info!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try **scrollToIndex(params: object)** method? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#scrolltoindex

And also if you want to update your data inside flatList you should add **extraData** in Props
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#extradata

If you use react-navigation goBack() to a screen, that screen will never trigger componentWillMount because this screen never unmount, so please use redux instead.